# MySQL вернуть если одно из значений true

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день коллеги.
Возник вопрос, есть массив ID юзеров
По ним необходимо получить массив соответсвующих первому массиву значений
в таблице колонки
ID VALUE

Как мне это организовать?

Верно ли я начал копать ?
SELECT value FROM `tablename` WHERE id = ANY (3, 4);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении команды

```
SELECT value FROM tablename WHERE id = ANY (3, 4);
```

вы получите ошибку. Вместо `= ANY` используйте `IN`:

```
SELECT value FROM tablename WHERE id IN (3, 4);
```

Подробнее об употреблении `ANY` и `IN` можно почитать [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь.